# OOP concepts In a console application

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm currently trying to improve my skills in Java. I have created a simple console-based bank system with four classes. A user interface, account holder, abstract bank account class which account holder extends, and finally a main to run the UI.

Basically, I want to get some suggested improvements and ideas on how to improve it and maybe implement some more OOP concepts.

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
         
         UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(myObj);
         ui.start();
         

    }

}
```

```
public class UserInterface {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private AccountHolder accountHolder;
    private Map<String, AccountHolder> accounts;

    public UserInterface(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
        this.accounts = new HashMap<String, AccountHolder>();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the bank please select from the options below by pressing the required number");
            System.out.println("1 - Create Account");
            System.out.println("2 - Log into account");
            System.out.println("3 - Quit");
            System.out.print("Please make a choice: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            switch(input) {
            case "1": 
                createAccount();
                break;
            case "2":
                login();
                break;
            case "3":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
                break;
            }       
        }
    }
    
    private void createAccount() {
        
        System.out.println("Please enter a username");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a password");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter name:");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter address:");
        String address = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter mobile number:");
        String number = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an initial deposit ammount");
        double deposit = scanner.nextDouble();
        
        accountHolder = new AccountHolder(username, password, name, address, number, deposit);
        accounts.put(username, accountHolder);
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    
    private void login() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your username");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your password");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();
        
        if(accounts.containsKey(username)) {
            accountHolder = accounts.get(username);
            if(accountHolder.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println("Please make a choice");
                    System.out.println("1 - Deposit");
                    System.out.println("2 - Withdraw");
                    System.out.println("3 - Balance");
                    System.out.println("4 - User information");
                    System.out.println("5 - Logout");
                    System.out.print("Please make a choice: ");
                    
                    String choice = scanner.nextLine();
                    switch(choice) {
                    case "1": 
                        System.out.println("Please enter an ammount to deposit");
                        double deposit = scanner.nextDouble();
                        accountHolder.deposit(deposit);
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("Please enter an ammount to withdraw");
                        double withdraw = scanner.nextDouble();
                        accountHolder.withdraw(withdraw);
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + accountHolder.getBalance());
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        System.out.println(accountHolder);
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid option");
                            
                    }       
                }
                
                
                
            }
        }
    
    }


}
```

```
public class AccountHolder extends BankAccount {

    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private double deposit;
    
    
    
    

    public AccountHolder(String username, String password, String name, String address, String mobileNumber, double deposit) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.deposit = deposit;


    }

    
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.mobileNumber;
    }
    
    public String getusername() {
        return this.username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }



    @Override
    double getBalance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.deposit += super.balance;
    }
    
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name +  "\n" + this.address+  "\n" + this.mobileNumber+  "\n" + super.getRandomAccountNumber()+  "\n" + super.getRandomSortcode();
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class BankAccount {
    
    protected double balance;
    
    public BankAccount() {
        
        this.balance = 0;
        this.sortcode = "";
        this.accountNumber = "";
        
    }
    
    abstract double getBalance();

    public void withdraw(double moneyWithdrawn) {
    this.balance -= moneyWithdrawn;
    }
    public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
    this.balance += depositAmount;
    }
    
    public String getRandomSortcode() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int newSortcode = rnd.nextInt(999999);
        
        return String.format("%06d", newSortcode);
    }
    
    public String getRandomAccountNumber() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int newAccountNum = rnd.nextInt(999999);
        
        return String.format("%08d", newAccountNum);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in more general review comments (code style, variable naming, etc), rather than just OOP principle related suggestions?

Comment: A bit of everything really, im just trying to improve in every aspect weather that be general comments or other OOP suggestions

Comment: As an additional note: `System.exit` is not a "soft" exit, but rather a hard kill of the JVM process (f.e. `finally` blocks will not be executed). It might or might not be wanted to do that.

Answer (score 12):

### Single Responsibility

My first piece of advice is to remember the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Take, for example, your `login` method in your `UserInterface` class, which is currently handling the rendering of the login inputs, checking whether it was a successful login, and then a host of bank account related operations.

Instead, we ought to have something more [cohesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)).

```
private void login() {
    System.out.println("Please enter your username");
    String username = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your password");
    String password = scanner.nextLine();
    if (new Authenticator(username, password).authenticate()) {
        presentAccountOperations();
    }
}
```

Your `UserInterface` class is also managing accounts which probably ought to be handled by a dedicated class.

### Inversion of Control

Typically it is best to leave the creation of "dependencies" to another class rather than handling them inside the class that needs them. So rather than calling `new AccountManager()` or `new Authenticator()` inside the `UserInterface` we ought to pass them in already created. We call this [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). For example we could do the following;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);       
     Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
     AccountManager accountManager = new AccountManager(authenticator);
     UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(myObj, accountManager);
     ui.start();       
}
```

### Composition over Inheritance

Your `AccountHolder` currently extends `BankAccount`. This is violating both the single responsibility principle, and it is semantically incorrect. A person with an account is not a type of bank account. Here is where you will want to know about the [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle.

It is better for an `AccountHolder` to ***have a*** `BankAccount`, rather than extending one. Additionally, if we want our account holder to have multiple bank accounts then we can change this relatively easily (which is not true if you use inheritance).

### Consistent Styling

People have differing opinions of how code should be styled, but something everyone agrees on is that the way you style your code should be consistent. The first thing that stands out to me from your code's styling and formatting is the number of new lines separating each section.

In some places you have 4 or more lines under your object fields, 2 at the end of method before the closing brace, 2 after the closing brace, 2 after one constructor but not others, and one between methods. [The Oracle java code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) recommends only 1 new line between methods, constructors, fields, and logical sections in code.

If you decide to leave 1 new line after method declarations it is better to do this always, or not at all. Consistency is key.

Comment: Thank you for your response, in regards to the abstract bank account class, would it make more sense to say create classes such as savings acount, debit account and then those extend the bank acount class?

Comment: @dawnofwar Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Right okay, my next question would be how would i then let the user choose which bank account they want using my user interface? Thank you for all your comments i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract interface from `UserInterface` class to use several realizations of app functionality

```
public interface UserInterface {
    public void start();
}
```

And usage:

```
public class ConsoleUserInterface implements UserInterface {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private AccountHolder accountHolder;
    private Map<String, AccountHolder> accounts;

    public ConsoleUserInterface(Scanner scanner) {
...
```

main:

```
UserInterface ui = new ConsoleUserInterface(myObj);
ui.start();
```